# Is there an efficient way to add a bulk amount of records each one does not exist with EF & SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

So I have a program that processes a lot of data, it pulls the data from the source then saves it into the database. The only conditions is that there cannot be duplicates based on just a single name field, there is no way to only pull new data, I have to pull it all.

The way I have it working right now is that it pulls all the data from the source, then all of the data from the DB (~1.5m records) then compares and only sends the new entries, however this is not very good in terms of RAM since it can use up around 700mb.
I looked into a way to let the DB handle more of the processing and found the below extension method on another question, but my concerns with using it is that it might be even more inefficient due to having to check 200 000 singularly against all records in the db

```
public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
{
    var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
    return !exists ? dbSet.Add(entity) : null;
}
```

So, any ideas as to how I might be able to handle this problem in an efficient manner?

Comment: For this kind of upsert, personally I'd probably skip EF and use a stored procedure with a Table Valued Parameter to do the merge.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to use Stored Procedures but it deffinately sounds like the way to go with this task

Comment: @Toxicable: what is the amount of source rows ?

Comment: It changes but can be near on 200k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Just a suggestion: because this task seems to be "data intensive" you could use a dedicated tool: SSIS. Create one package having one `Data Flow Task` thus:

- OLE DB source (to read data from source)
- Lookup transformation (to check if every source value exists or not within target table; This needs indexing)
- No match data flow (source value doesn't exist) then
- OLE DB destination (it inserts the source value into target table).

I would use this approach if I have to compare/search on small set of columns (this columns should be indexed).

2) Another suggestion: is to simply insert source data into #TempTable and then

```
INSERT dbo.TargetTable (...)
SELECT ...
FROM #TempTable
EXCEPT
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.TargetTable
```

I would use this approach if I have to compare/search on all columns.

You have to do your tests to see which is the right/fastest approach.

Comment: I do like the sounds of this, but I have not looked at SSIS, ill be checking them out now

Comment: After looking into SSIS a bit more, I think I might go with the temp table approach for this problem but look into SSIS later on if im in need of it again

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to EF, there's a few ways of improving your algorithm:

1. Download only Name field from your source table (create a new DTO object that maps to the same table but contains only the name field against which you compare). That will minimize the memory usage.
2. Create and store the hash of the name field in the database. Then download on the client only hashes. Check the input data - if there's no hash, just add it; if there's such hash - check with dbSet.Any(..). If you use the MD5 hash it will take only 16 (bytes) *1,5M records ~ 23Mb. If you use CRC32, 4*1,5 records ~ 6Mb.
3. You have the high memory usage because all the data you added is stored in the DB context. If you do in chunks (let's say 4000 records) and then close the context, the memory will be released.

   ```
               using (var context = new MyDBContext())
               {
                   context.DBSet.Add(...); // and no more than 4000 records here.
                   context.SaveChanges();
               }
   ```

The better solution is to use SQL statements that can be executed via

```
model.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT...", 
    new SqlParameter("Name",..), 
    new SqlParameter("Value",..));
```

(Mind to set the parameter type for SqlParameter)

```
INSERT target(name, value)
SELECT @Name, @Value
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM target WHERE name = @Name);
```

If the expected number of inserted values is high, you might get benefits form using Table type (System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured) (assuming you use MS SQL server) and executing the similar query in some chunks but it is a little bit more complex.

Depending on the SQL server you may download the data into a temporary table (e.g. you have a CSV file or BulkInsert for MS SQL) and then execute the similar query.

Comment: The solution of using MD5 hash is a good `start` but it needs something more because there are hash collisions => two diff. rows (and values) can have the same hash.

Comment: I mentioned it `if there's such hash - check with dbSet.Any(..).`. Maybe it was too short explained.